# Is it possible to encrypt all files in a folder including their file names but totally without compression using 7zip?

Tags: linux, encryption, 7-zip

I have a folder with several files:

```
file1
file2
file3
```

I want to encrypt them all with AES including the file names so the output should be something like this:

```
kjk437fjk437
3k4jn34jk
j34nkj34
```

But I do not want to apply any compression at all.

Is it possible to do this with 7zip? I am using Debian and looking for Terminal based solutions only.

Edit: I also want to be able to get the filename back after decryption.

Comment: Please clarify your requirements: why do you need to avoid compression?

Comment: Did you think of encrypting the filenames in an extra step as simple string encryption?

Answer (score 2):

You probably just want to hide the filename instead of to encrypt it, so something like the following should do:

```
for file in ./*;do 
  7z a $RANDOM-$RANDOM.7z -m1=copy -mhe -psecret "$file"; 
  rm "$file" 
done
```

`-m1=copy` means use copy method, so no compression.
`-mhe` means encrypt header, so without password one cannot view filenames inside the 7z file.
`-psecret` sets password to `secret`

Comment: Interesting. But how can I get the filename back when I want to decrypt again?

Comment: @Vesa the original filename is stored in the archive. You get the original file + filename back just by extracting it.

Comment: And this also AES encrypts the content of the file?

Comment: @Vesa I believe it does.

Comment: I will test it soon

Comment: Seems to work. Will apply some further testing. By the way I read somewhere that it's not recommended to use 7zip for backups because owner/group is not stored. What does it mean and can I still use 7zip for backup?

Comment: @Vesa you are probably right. I believe 7zip was originally created for windows, then later ported to Linux, so it's support for permission/ownership might not be very good. But I'm not an expert on that, so cannot provide more details. I would recommend you do some research yourself, I'm sure there are already plenty of resources out there(or here on stackexchange) .

Answer (score 0):

Is 7zip a must? Choose the right tool. [EncFS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/EncFS) seems to be it.

1. Install it. In Debian: `apt-get install encfs`.
2. Create two directories: `mkdir encrypted mountpoint`.
3. Run the tool:

   ```
   encfs "$PWD/encrypted" "$PWD/mountpoint"
   ```

   Note you need `$PWD/` instead of `./` because `encfs` doesn't accept relative paths (unless `-f` is used).
4. Proceed as instructed to choose encryption, password.
5. Copy or move all directories and files you want to encrypt to `./mountpoint`. Encrypted directories and files will appear in the `./encrypted` directory.
6. Unmount:

   ```
   fusermount -u ./mountpoint
   ```

You can now copy/move/rename/tar/whatever the `./encrypted` directory *as a whole*. Note there is a hidden `.xml` file inside. The file includes the (password protected) key which is crucial, so don't lose it. It's possible to store the file separetely (read about `ENCFS6_CONFIG` variable in `man 1 encfs`).

To access the original files, repeat step 3, provide the right password. Work with files under the chosen mountpoint: read, add, remove, modify, anything goes. Finally unmount with `fusermount -u` like in step 6.

Notes:

- `encfs` is FUSE (filesystem in userspace). See [*Why FUSE might be considered insecure on server?*](https://superuser.com/a/1242432/432690)
- There are also [EncFS-specific security concerns](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/EncFS#General_security_concerns).

Comment: Cannot use encfs on this device, otherwise I would as I used to before.

Comment: @Vesa It's somewhat disappointing you knew about `encfs` and you knew you can't use it now, still you didn't explicitly ruled it out. I did notice you're asking about a 7zip solution; but sticking to some tool is often a Y in [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378/355310), while good answers should concentrate on X and this is what I was trying to do. The answer will stay (with other users in mind), unless you change the question so it clearly says `encfs` is not an option. Regardless, I do hope you'll get an answer that fits *you*. Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

You could encrypt your folder twice to hide your file names:

```
type="zip"; file="your-folder"; password="your-password"; # You also could use other formats.

7z a -t"$type" "$file.$type" -p"$password" "$file"
7z a -t"$type" "$file.$type.$type" -p"$password" "$file.$type"
```

Then the file `"your-folder.zip.zip"` is what you want.