# What happens to sshfs mounted folders in `/tmp`

Tags: linux, sshfs

As the title suggests, I was wondering what happens to via `sshfs` mounted folders if they are mapped to a subfolder of `/tmp`, e.g., `/tmp/data`. Are they simply unmounted or is the data removed recursively from the remote server as well?

Comment: (1) `sshfs` is FUSE. Do you mount as root? Or do you use `allow_other` or `allow_root` as non-root? (see the beginning of [this answer](https://superuser.com/a/1531417/432690)). (2) Is the mount persistent? (does it survive reboot?). (3) Is your `/tmp` `tmpfs`? ([it may or may not be](https://superuser.com/a/1030777/432690)). (4) What distro are you using? (handling `/tmp` [was distro-dependent in 2012](https://serverfault.com/a/377349) and I suspect it still is ([because](https://xkcd.com/927/))). (5) If you suspect mounting in `/tmp` may destroy your data, simply don't mount in `/tmp`.

Comment: Hi Thank you for your commant. I am no root user on the machine, so `sshfs` is executed in user-mode. the mount does not have to survive reboot (it is not part of `/etc/fstab`). `/tmp` is part of a hard drive. The distro is Ubuntu 20.04.

Comment: Please [edit] the question and add this information to the question body.