# How to enter gvfs on terminal as the superuser?

Tags: linux, bash, terminal, permissions, kali-linux

I am trying to access gvfs as the **superuser** but I can't for some reason; whenever I try to do so, I get this: `ls: cannot access 'gvfs': permission denied`

Any idea why this happened and how to enter gvfs?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Are you trying to access another user's FUSE mountpoint? E.g. `/run/user/1000/gvfs`? The beginning of [this answer about SSHFS](https://superuser.com/a/1531417/432690) applies to any FUSE filesystem. If the user mounted by hand and specified `allow_root` or `allow_other` then you probably could access the directory as root. Maybe it's an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378/355310). Why do you want to access another user's gvfs?