# How can I input from a file to step thru it as a filesystem

Tags: linux, files-folders

I have a file that has a listing of files/folders with the full paths. I'm looking for a way to be able to run thru this as if it was a filesystem.

I attached a small part of this file (the original is 33MB with over 460,000 lines)

```
./
./termux/
./termux/apt.tar
./termux/usr/
./termux/usr/lib/
./termux/usr/lib/libthread_db.so.1
./termux/usr/lib/libpython3.11.so.1.0
./termux/usr/lib/libgssapi_krb5.so.2.2
./termux/usr/lib/libTECkit.so
./termux/usr/lib/gnome-settings-daemon-3.0/
./termux/usr/lib/gnome-settings-daemon-3.0/gtk-modules/
./termux/usr/lib/gnome-settings-daemon-3.0/gtk-modules/at-spi2-atk.desktop
./termux/usr/lib/qt/
./termux/usr/lib/qt/mkspecs/
./termux/usr/lib/qt/mkspecs/integrity-armv7/
./termux/usr/lib/qt/mkspecs/integrity-armv7/qplatformdefs.h
./termux/usr/lib/qt/mkspecs/integrity-armv7/qmake.conf
./termux/usr/lib/qt/mkspecs/dummy/
./termux/usr/lib/gnome-settings-daemon-3.0/gtk-modules/canberra-gtk-module.desktop
...
./ubuntu-fs/
./ubuntu-fs/home/
...
./Other/
./Other/temp/
./Other/temp/Month.db
./Other/2021/
./Other/2021/January.txt
./Other/2021/February.txt
...
```

What I would like to do is something as follows

start with the root folder `/`

`ls` should give the listing of root

```
termux/
ubuntu-fs/
Other/
...
```

`cd termux` should take me into the `termux` folder
`ls` now would list everything in the `termux` folder

```
apt.tar
usr/
...
```

And so on ...

I't doesn't need to work specifically with `ls` & `cd`. This is just to explain the idea I'm looking for.

Comment: What about prepending each line ending with a slash with `mkdir` and the rest with `touch`. Then run it as a script in a temp directory and you can use the shell itself to navigate the files.

Comment: Can you explain what the difference between your question and the output of `find /` would need to be?

Comment: @LjmDullaart `find /` would be looking at my current filesystem I;m lookin for something that would use the information from the file **as if** it is a filesystem

Comment: @choroba This would mean creating a whole filesystem I don't want to create it just traces it from the file. The info in the file is from a backed up filesystem and I need from time to time to traves it and see some of the files and folder structure.

Comment: I second @choroba suggestion with an optonal addtional step: create the the folders and empty files in a temp directory. Then, optionally, zip it into a compressed folder. Then you have a single file you can quickly extract when you want your "dummy" file system.

Comment: The most elegant solution would be FUSE that actually mounts the file. Is creating it worth the hassle? Maybe. An archive or a filesystem (like SquashFS) created from a temporary directory populated by running many `mkdir -p` and `touch` commands may work as well; or even better, because some archive formats and some filesystems are *already* mountable as FUSE. A bird in the hand is worth two in the bush.

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski How can I mount it with FUSE? BTW I tried using archivemount on the archive but any command I ran on a big folder in the archive caused it to hang (or seemed to hang since I gave up waiting for the command to work after a couple of hours).

Comment: You cannot, until you (or someone) write a FUSE exactly for this (I'm not aware of any existing solution). I have no experience with archivemount, I guess the number of files affects the performance badly. A decent filesystem should perform better. With root access you can mount filesystems of any type supported by Linux. Without root access you should pick a filesystem type that can be mounted as FUSE. I mentioned SquashFS but I don't really know if it's particularly good for the task.

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski Actually this is just a text file if the folder/file hierarchy of the file within an archive. I was hoping that traversing the hierarchy would be simpler and quicker with a text file rather than the actual archive.

Comment: I concur with Kamil; the only feasible solution without actually creating the hierarchy is to _implement_ a virtual filesystem (FUSE or otherwise) that presents the hierarchy. I _strongly_ recommend not doing this. Use _tmpfs_ instead and just create the hierarchy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This answer will allow you to do the following:

1. According to the listing, create a hierarchy of directories and regular files in a directory of your choice. This is itself a solution because you will be able to browse the hierarchy with `cd`+`ls`, `mc` or whatever.
2. (Optionally) Using the hierarchy, create a SquashFS image for convenient mounting (even as a regular user) in the future.

---

#### 1. Creating a hierarchy

Take this script:

```sh
#!/bin/sh -
file="$1"
dir="$2"

mkdir -p -- "$dir" || { echo >&2 'Cannot create directory.'; exit 1; }

<"$file" grep '^\./.*/$'    | tr '\n' '\0' | (cd "$dir" && xargs -0 mkdir -p --)
<"$file" grep '^\./.*[^/]$' | tr '\n' '\0' | (cd "$dir" && xargs -0 touch    --)
```

Save it as `txt2dir`, make it executable (`chmod +x txt2dir`) and use like this:

```
./txt2dir /path/to/listing /path/to/directory
```

`/path/to/directory` may or may not exist yet. It will be created if needed. Specifying a non-empty directory is possible, but probably you would want to use an empty or not-yet-existing directory.

Notes:

- `/path/to/directory` may be [`/dev/shm/something`](https://superuser.com/a/45509/432690) for performance.
- The listing is processed twice. Directories (from lines ending with `/`) are created first, regular files (from lines not ending with `/`) are created later. If in the listing some entry for a regular file precedes the entry for its directory, this will still work.
- I assume that for every line not ending with `/` there exists a line ending with `/` that describes all directories in the path. In other words, when `touch` tries to create a regular file (e.g. `./foo/bar/baz`), all directories it needs are already there because `mkdir` has created them (`./foo/bar/` was in the listing).

  If this is not necessarily the case (i.e. if `./foo/bar/` may be missing), replace `grep '…'` in the line with `mkdir` with `sed -n '\|^\./| s|/[^/]*$||p'`. This variant will use all entries to create necessary directories (e.g. `./foo/bar/baz` alone will be enough to create `./foo/bar/`), so when `touch` starts, all directories will be there for sure. This will be at the cost of performance.
- Your listing uses newline characters as delimiters, but I don't let them enter `xargs`. With `tr` I convert them to null characters, then I use `xargs -0`. `xargs -0` is the best way to process entries verbatim, without treating backslashes and quotes specially; it's not portable though. Any portable solution has its quirks and/or downsides, I won't elaborate.
- The regular expressions for `grep` (or `sed`) deliberately omit lines not starting with `./`. This is in case some original pathname contained a newline character and generated more than one line in the listing. Example:

  ```
  ./foo/bar/dir with
  newline character/baz
  ```

  From the above pair only the first line will be processed. Unfortunate filenames will be truncated, unfortunate directories will appear as regular files; but at least there will be no misleading garbage in the top-level directory (`newline character/baz`, if created, would be such garbage).

  Since ultimately we use `xargs -0`, a better approach (but I'm not going to implement it) would be to detect such cases and deal with them, keeping newlines that belong to pathnames and converting others to null characters. Still pathnames with newline-dot-slash substring would deceive even this.

  Hopefully the hierarchy you created your listing from did not contain pathnames with newline characters.

And here you go. A browsable hierarchy is in `/path/to/directory`. When no longer needed, you can remove it with `rm -r /path/to/directory`. Keep the script and the listing and restore the hierarchy anytime; or proceed with SquashFS (keep reading).

---

#### 2. Creating and using a SquashFS image

Having a hierarchy created with the above script, you can now create a SquashFS image. If the hierarchy is in `/path/to/directory`, the command to create an image is:

```
mksquashfs /path/to/directory image.sqfs
```

Now you can mount the filesystem:

- as root with

  ```
   mount -t squashfs image.sqfs /path/to/mountpoint
  ```
- or as a regular user with

  ```
   squashfuse image.sqfs /path/to/mountpoint
  ```

  (this requires [FUSE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Filesystem_in_Userspace) to be supported and enabled in your OS).

And now you can browse `/path/to/mountpoint`. The hierarchy in `/path/to/directory` is no longer needed. Keep the image and mount/unmount it at will.

Notes:

- To unmount after `mount` use `umount /path/to/mountpoint` as root; to unmount after `squashfuse` use `fusermount -u /path/to/mountpoint` as the user.
- `squashfuse` uses [FUSE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Filesystem_in_Userspace). See these:

  - [*Why FUSE might be considered insecure on server?*](https://superuser.com/a/1242432/432690)
  - [*How to mount FUSE so that all users will have access to it?*](https://superuser.com/a/1758136/432690)
- Due to compression, the image will most likely be smaller than the listing. If convenient browsing is all you wanted then you may delete the listing and work with the image only.

---

#### Addendum

This is the command I used to create a listing that resembles your listing:

```
( cd /path/to/hierarchy && find . ! -type d -print -o -exec printf '%s/\n' {} \; ) > listing
```

I also used it for creating listings from hierarchies created from the original listing. This and `diff <(sort listing) <(sort listing2)` in Bash allowed me to test if my script works well.

Comment: Your first option worked great. I haven't had a chance to try `squashfuse`. Would you be able to explain the last 2 lines of the script what each part does, I would like to learn from it.

Comment: @Sruly I don't know what you know, I don't know what you don't know. To fully explain, I would need to elaborate on `<`, shell variables, quoting in a shell, `grep` with regular expressions (including at least wildcards, some anchors, escaping, bracket expressions), pipelines, `tr` with `\X` notation, subshells, `&&`, `xargs`, why `xargs -0` is good, `mkdir -p`, `touch`, double-dash. This is not how this site is supposed to work; each topic should be explained under its own specific question. Are there parts you understand? Are there parts you totally don't understand?

Comment: I appreciate any help you can give. The main part I need help with is the first part `<"$file"` How does the `<` work. Also how does it know where to create the file (or Folder) in this part `(cd "$dir" && xargs -0 mkdir -p --)`

Comment: @Sruly For `<` see [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/356118), [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/740005), maybe [this](https://superuser.com/q/1335333). Paths in your file are relative (they start with `./`) and my `grep`s deliberately filter out other paths. What `mkdir -p` or `touch` get as arguments are these relative paths, but they run *after* the subshell I deliberately created successfully ([`&&`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/159513)) [performs `cd` to `$dir`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/13802). This is how I set working directory for `mkdir` or `touch` to `$dir`.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I just want to clarify one thing. You mention **subshell I deliberately created**, is the subshell created by the parentheses `(` `)`?

Comment: Trying `sudo mount -vt squashfs ext4-fs-backup-2023-03-05.sqfs t` I get this result
`try 'ext4-fs-backup-2023-03-05.sqfs' type 'squashfs' on 't'
mount: 'ext4-fs-backup-2023-03-05.sqfs'->'t': No such device`.
I was able to to mount with `squashfuse` using the following command `sudo squashfuse -o allow_other ext4-fs-backup-2023-03-05.sqfs t`. I was just wondering why the mount option isn't working and what I may be doing wrong.

Comment: @Sruly Yes, I deliberately created a subshell by using the parentheses. I think it's unspecified if `sh` shall execute the last part of a pipeline in a subshell or not. I needed a subshell because I wanted to `cd` "for a while", so I explicitly requested a subshell.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a proof of concept of a simple Perl program that does what you need (but I didn't handle all the possible edge cases). Give it the input file name as an argument.

```perl
#!/usr/bin/perl
use warnings;
use strict;
use feature qw{ say };

sub dir :lvalue {
    my ($fs, @dirs) = @_;
    return '.' unless @dirs;
    return $fs->{ $dirs[0] } if 1 == @dirs;
    return dir($fs->{ $dirs[0] }, @dirs[1 .. $#dirs])
}

my %fs;
while (<>) {
    chomp;
    my $is_dir = m{/$};
    my @dirs = split m{/};
    my $last = pop @dirs;
    if ($is_dir) {
        dir(\%fs, @dirs, $last) = {};
    } else {
        dir(\%fs, @dirs)->{$last} = undef;
    }
}

my $current = '.';

sub ls {
    my @args = @_;
    @args = ("") unless @args;
    for my $arg (@args) {
        if ($arg !~ m{^/}) {
            substr $arg, 0, 0, "$current/";
        }
        my @dirs = updirs(split m{/}, $arg);
        for my $member (sort keys %{ dir(\%fs, @dirs) }) {
            print $member;
            say dir(\%fs, @dirs)->{$member} ? '/' : "";
        }
    }
}

sub cd {
    my @args = @_;
    warn "One argument expected.\n" unless 1 == @args;
    my @dirs = updirs(split m{/},
                      ($args[0] =~ m{^/}) ? $args[0] : "$current/$args[0]");
    if (ref dir(\%fs, @dirs)) {
        $current = join '/', @dirs;
    } else {
        warn "Non-existent path.\n";
    }
}

my %dispatch = (ls   => \&ls,
                cd   => \&cd,
                exit => sub { exit });
while (print({*STDERR} "$current: "), $_ = <STDIN>) {
    chomp;
    my ($command, @args) = split;
    warn "Unknown command '$command'.\n"
        unless exists $dispatch{$command};
    $dispatch{$command}->(@args);
}

sub updirs {
    my @dirs = @_;
    shift @dirs if "" eq $dirs[0];
    for (my $i = 0; $i <= $#dirs; ++$i) {
        if ($dirs[$i] eq '..') {
            if ($i > 0) {
                splice @dirs, $i - 1, 2;
                $i -= 2;
            } else {
                splice @dirs, 0, 1;
                $i = -1;
            }
        }
    }
    return @dirs
}
```

Comment: I'm not familiar at all with perl so I can't do much with this example. There is no indication which files are files and which are folders. (In my post you can see the folders end with the folders mark `/`)

Comment: Updated to mark directories.

Comment: I'm getting this error `Can't return undef from lvalue subroutine at ./test-fs line 10, <> line 1.`

Comment: When do you get the error? At the start of the script or after entering some commands - in such a case, which ones? Have you specified the input file as an argument?

Comment: At the start of the script

Comment: Do you provide the input file as an argument to the script? What's the content of the first line in the file?

Comment: I had provided it as an arg on the command line I don't have the file anymore since I went with Kamil's answer.  I believe the first line was the same as in my question.

Comment: That's weird. The sample file you provided works with the code without problems (when I remove the ellipsis).